# How to controll the layout from another class?

Tags: android

I have some `TextView` that shows average value , and then i have a class has a`AlertDialog` method , i want user click ok and update my `TextView` value .

I get the error show `java.lang.NullPointerException:`

Some one can teach me how to fix it and complete what i want , thanks in advance.

The `TextView` layout class extends Fragment:

```
    public class MyDailyInput extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

        private Context context;

    @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_daily_input, container, false);
//contact is my data object , it has data i'm sure.
new DialogHandler(getActivity()).
                                updateDialog(getResources().getString(R.string.update),
                                        getResources().getString(R.string.cancel), contact);


            return view;
    }

        // Set the average value method
        public void setAverageValue(Context context){
            avBeMorning.setText(String.valueOf(av.beforeMorning()));
            avAfMorning.setText(String.valueOf(av.afterMorning()));
            avBeNoon.setText(String.valueOf(av.beforeNoon()));
            avAfNoon.setText(String.valueOf(av.afterNoon()));
            avBeNight.setText(String.valueOf(av.beforeNight()));
            avAfNight.setText(String.valueOf(av.afterNight()));
        }
```

Here is my class that controll AlertDialog:

```
public class DialogHandler extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DatabaseHandler db =null;
    private Context context;

    public DialogHandler(Context context){
        this.context = context;
        db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
    }

    // AlertDialog
    public void updateDialog(String rightMessage, String leftMessage, final Contact contact) {
        android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setMessage(context.getResources().getString(R.string.dataExisted))
                .setPositiveButton(rightMessage, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        System.out.println("try to update");
                        Toast.makeText(context,context.getResources().getString(R.string.updatedSucceed),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        db.updateContact(contact);
                        // I try to use this code to 
                        // change my TextView value of 
                        // MyDailyInut layout , but i get error.
                        new MyDailyInput().setAverageValue(context);
                    }
                });
        builder.setNegativeButton(leftMessage, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: did you create new activity `DialogHandler`  just to show alert dialog?

Comment: use local broadcast

Comment: @Redman , yes i did it...any good idea ?

Comment: you have to call broadcast or custom listner over there

Comment: I think if u call dialog directly at MyDailyInput  fragment yr problem will solved

Comment: Thanks for reply , i have less experience with broadcast and listener , has any suggestion to start ?

Comment: It will be solved exactly , but i want to practice that put some code on the same class , just like the question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a interface in fragment and activity should implement the method of that interface and initialise the interface on fragment's onCreate method.

//Fragment

```
  public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {
     private OnClicked call;

     public interface OnClicked {
        void gotoActivity(int value);
     }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context){
    super.onAttach(context);
    call = (OnClicked) context;
}

    //any event
    call.gotoActivity(your average value);
   }


  public class RandomActivity extends Activity implements FragmentOne.OnClicked {

   @Override
   public void gotoActivity(int value) {
    // do here
   }
  }
```

Comment: How to create a succeed interface , i don't use interface too much , can you show me some point ?

Answer (score 0):

Create alertDialog inside fragment itself instead of creating new activity

use `getActivity()`   instead of `context`

```
    public class MyDailyInput extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

        private Context context;

    @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_daily_input, container, false);

                                updateDialog(getResources().getString(R.string.update),
                                        getResources().getString(R.string.cancel), contact);


            return view;
    }

        // Set the average value method
        public void setAverageValue(Context context){
            avBeMorning.setText(String.valueOf(av.beforeMorning()));
            avAfMorning.setText(String.valueOf(av.afterMorning()));
            avBeNoon.setText(String.valueOf(av.beforeNoon()));
            avAfNoon.setText(String.valueOf(av.afterNoon()));
            avBeNight.setText(String.valueOf(av.beforeNight()));
            avAfNight.setText(String.valueOf(av.afterNight()));
        }





public void updateDialog(String rightMessage, String leftMessage, final Contact contact) {
        android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setMessage(getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.dataExisted))
                .setPositiveButton(rightMessage, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        System.out.println("try to update");
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.updatedSucceed),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        db.updateContact(contact);
                        // I try to use this code to 
                        // change my TextView value of 
                        // MyDailyInut layout , but i get error.
                       setAverageValue(getActivity());
                    }
                });
        builder.setNegativeButton(leftMessage, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer , but is any way to complete it by creating another class ? I just stuck right the point.